# jQuery multiple file reading not working

Tags: jquery, html

jQuery:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
                if($("#img"+i).val() != ''){
                    file = document.getElementById('img' + i).files[0];
                    fileread(file);
                }
            }

function fileread(file){
        var result = '';
        reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){
                result = reader.result;
                //return result;
                localStorage.setItem("lostimage1", result);

            }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="img1" id="img1">
<input type="file" name="img2" id="img2">
<input type="file" name="img3" id="img3">
<input type="file" name="img4" id="img4">
```

Anyone can Please help me it reading the first file but not reading file number 2, 3, 4. all file input fields are filled with the file.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're only defining one localstorage field:

```
$('input:file').each(function(i){
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this != ''){
      fileread( $this[0].files[0] , i ); // send file and position
   }
});  // using jquery each for any number of file fields

function fileread(file , num){
    var reader = new FileReader(),
        num = "lostimage" + (num + 1); // set the location name
        reader.onload = function(){
            localStorage.setItem(num , reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

unable to test presently but let me know in comments if this works?